# Linking to Pirate Bay for open source content?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I'm publicizing some ChromiumOS build torrents via the Pirate Bay and would like to share that link in the chat and possibly refer to it if relevant for an answer.

Due to the controversy that exists for the site, I felt best to check here before doing something that could be perceived as unacceptable.

Comment: Or you can add the distro to distrowatch, etc... etc...

Comment: I don't see how there could be a problem if it's OS software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharing links to legal content isn't a problem in itself, even if it's to a torrent on Pirate Bay. However, this may trigger the ire of some corporate firewalls. So I would recommend avoiding doing it on the main site. In chat, though, I think it's ok. If you link to “dodgy” sites such as Pirate Bay, be sure to warn people who might be tempted in clicking on the link that it's [NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSFW).

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I read up on a few more metas about [NSFW links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121312/197141) and along with the comments above, all should be clear now.

Comment: Of course, also consider the possibility that such a link may become useless even more quickly than most links to more static resources such as web pages.